# Does Alexandria's Genesis exist?

Tags: biology

Supposedly, it's a mutation that gives you purple eyes at puberty, no hair, and for women, fertility without menstruations.

[image: Illustration of the phenomenon]

[Source](http://solarflaresinmymind.tumblr.com/post/4536728191)

Comment: I think "women also menstruate, but are fertile" is an easy give away of it being fake

Comment: Clearly Alexandria's Genesis doesn't exist because it claims that the people with it have no hair, and quoting the article they have no eyelashes, but in this picture the person has eyelashes.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The origins appear to be invented in some fan fiction. There's no reference to it in Google Scholar, which covers abstracts from a huge number of scientific papers.

Cameron Miquelon [claims to be the original author](http://33avenuemiquelon.com/2011/12/16/alexandrias-genesis-meet-the-creator-behind-the-fallacy/) in about 1998, and is frustrated by people who can't tell the difference between fiction and fact:

> Alas, what’s truly astonishing is that in spite of this post’s existence (as well as the true origin of Alexandria’s Genesis being a Daria fan fiction website), nothing has changed among the 99 percent of you who believe that what I wrote is truth, if my bookmarked Tumblr search tag is anything to go by.
>
> For that, I hate you all so very much.

[...]

> Anyway, there you have it: Alexandria’s Genesis is simply a bad mashup of Daria, Art Bell, Twilight, witchcraft and Cylon skinjobs adopted by New Agers and others who should know better, but don’t and won’t.

Comment: This is hilarious!

Comment: A perfect example of how 95% of myths are born.

Comment: "cylon skinjobs". Love the BSG reference.

Comment: [Snopes weighs in](http://www.snopes.com/politics/medical/alexandriasgenesis.asp), over two years later.